# Why list all Kosher Behaimos and their Simanim

Tags: kashrut-kosher, parashat-reeh

The Torah lists 10 Kosher Behaimos and then lists the Kosher simanim required (split hoofs, chews cud etc.) Why does it list both ? In Deuteronomy 14:4-5 it lists "these are the Behaimos that you may eat: ox,seh of sheep, seh of goats,hart, deer,yachmur,akko,dishon,te'o,and zemer. Rav Yitzxchok in Chullin 80A saysthat the Torah listed ***ALL*** the species that meet its criteria for permissibility. So the next pasuk that lists the simonim , only describes the simonim of these 10 animals.   My question is why list the animals and the simanim? one or the other would suffice?